# Can't parse some text within comment

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've tried to parse the content within comment from the below snippet but it doesn't seem to work at all. How can I make it work? My intention is to get the text within `p` tag and the output should be:

```
Hi there!!
Hi again!!
```

Script I've already tried with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

content="""
<!-- comment --><a href="https://extratorrent.ag/"><p>Hi there!!</p></a>
<!-- comment1 --><a href="https://thepiratebay.se/"><p>Hi again!!</p></a>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment)):
    data = BeautifulSoup(comment.next_element,"lxml")
    for item in data.select("p"):
        print(item.text)
```

The error I'm having:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Social.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = BeautifulSoup(comment.next_element,"lxml")
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 191, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: post full traceback of the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to `html.parser`, and then just access the `p` tag inside.

The advantage of the `html.parser` is that it does not add extra `<html><body>...</body></html>` tags around your soup data. You can then just access the contents of the `p` tag using `comment.next_element.p.text`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    print(comment.next_element.p.text)

Hi there!!
Hi again!!
```

Comment: Wow!!! It's a legendary fix. The system doesn't allow me to accept your answer before time comes. Given a plus one already. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @novice-coder You're welcome! Although you may want to ensure that your code does not error out when a comment is not succeeded by an anchor tag or a p tag. (Think, `try...except`) Good luck!